# jQuery not working after loading additional content

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

I am quite new to javascript, but I am using it at my website. Last week I found a script that loads additional content to my page via jQuery. Everything was all right until I noticed that my other scripts stopped working because of that. For example I have a script that binds checkboxes:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('.class_of_checkbox').click(
            function() {
                if(this.checked == true) {
                    $(".class_of other_checkbox").attr('checked', this.checked);
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
</script>
```

It is inline code. I have read that it could be caused by function ready(), which fires only when the DOM is loaded, but I am not sure how to solve this problem.

Comment: is your checkbox loaded dynamically or, its static ?

Comment: You should be using `.prop()` as well... `.prop('checked', this.checked);`

Comment: L load my checkbox dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic elements loaded with ajax needs delegated event handlers :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('change', '.class_of_checkbox', function() {
        if (this.checked) 
          $(".class_of other_checkbox").prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
```

Replace the second `document` with the closest non-dynamic parent, use `prop()` for properties, and use the `change` event to capture changes in the state of a checkbox.

Comment: Beat me to it! Don't know why this got down'd either. +1.

Comment: Me either. This is a perfect example of when you should use delegated events. +1

Comment: Why are you selecting document twice?  `$(function(){ $(this).on('change', '.class_of.....`

Comment: `this` is always the `document` inside a jQuery DOM ready function, but it's usually good practice to not use `this` to refer to it when writing delegated event handlers.

Comment: It's also not a good practice to perform redundant selections. Tit for tat.

Comment: But the window and document is always available, so there's no DOM lookup, and no overhead other than the jQuery wrapping to select it twice.

Comment: By the the "closest non-dynamic parent" you meant checkbox that should check when the script is running?

Comment: No, I meant the closest parent element that is'nt loaded with ajax. Normally the element that you insert the ajax loaded content into.

Comment: ok, I put there id of div that holds the loaded content, but still it doesnt work. What should i put there to make it working?

Answer (score 1):

Use $.ajaxComplete to rebind your actions when the ajax call completes

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $('.class_of_checkbox').click(
        function() {
            if(this.checked == true) {
                $(".class_of other_checkbox").attr('checked', this.checked);
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: $.ajaxComplete fires **everytime** an ajax call completes, rebinding the event to any elements currently on the page.